# Implementation differences between NS records and CNAME records for delegating control of a subdomain

Tags: dns, cname, ttl

I am wanting to control the destination IP address for `www.example.com` (but not `example.com`) using DNS and **exert the most control over this subdomain TTL** as I can since I do not have direct control of the parent domain itself. I am aware of 2 mechanisms I can use:

1. I can set up a zone for `www.example.com` in my name servers and have the name servers for `example.com` set up NS records for `www.example.com`.
2. I can use a CNAME to point `www.example.com` to `example.mydomain.com` and then control `example.mydomain.com`. This is probably simpler for the remote party to set up, as delegating using NS records is a lot less common in the circles I frequent.

What I am a little vague on is the subtleties of the ttl mechanisms - particularly around caching. If I use a CNAME, will the actual TTL be controlled by both the TTL on the `www.example.com` record AND the TTL on `example.mydomain.com`, or (provided the CNAME record does not change), is this tied only to the A record for `example.mydomain.com`.

Similarly, if I use NS entries, is it fair to say that (provided the nameservers do no not change), that the TTL for changes to the resolution of `www.example.com` is controlled by the TTL for the `www.example.com` A record and I don't need to worry about the TTL's of the NS records?

Comment: So just have to ask: Is there a concern about affecting the TTL for the parent/primary domain? Because honestly there should be not negative impact related to lowering the TTL for the parent domain so the subdomain can propagate.

Comment: @JakeGould I don't have control of the parent domains, save as to ask the person who does to make changes to the records.  In my experience, most people who are controlling DNS have a very limited understanding of what they are doing - to the point I'm hesitant to even ask for NS records in a subdomain!.  I don't want to open a can of worms of TTLs  (and at least one of the interfaces commonly used in this part of the world is scary badly written)

Comment: Got it! Sounds like a bad scenario. So hey, maybe someone knows something more about the topic than I do?

Comment: TTL applies to individual records, not to names and/or domains. So you can have a different TTL for the NS record and the A record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TTL of a record applies to that record and that record alone and starts expiring once it enters the cache of any given nameserver/caching-resolver.

Note that many (most?) caching nameservers (i.e. caching resolvers used by end clients) will put a minimum 300 second TTL on all records that are fetched with any lower value.  Note also there can be more than one caching nameserver between the client and the authoritative nameserver.

You probably want a relatively long TTL on any CNAME (or NS, MX, etc.) records, and possibly a much shorter (e.g. as short as 300s) TTL on any A records.

The simplest way to have someone delegate a hostname (e.g. `www.example.com`) to allow you to control the final A record is of course with a CNAME, but of course keep in mind that such a hostname must be a subdomain name, i.e. it cannot be at a zone cut since of course a CNAME may not exist with any other records at the same node.

For example in the parent domain nameserver:

```
$ORIGIN example.com.
www  1w  IN  CNAME  foo.mydomain.example.
```

Then in your nameserver:

```
$ORIGIN mydomain.example.
foo  1h  IN  A  192.168.0.1
```